# what is the difference between the two H2O.ai in this image. and why the text is automatically bold when entered in some text field

Tags: user-interface, unicode, operating-system, char, ascii

sorry as the stack overflow answer check was not allowing the native format which im trying to post. below are the 2 images however.

i was wondering why H2O.ai in question and regular H2O.ai are different. is it some sort of char map? i have seen that on many Instagram user descriptions. how to generate it and purpose behind it, any info  will be appreciated.

[image: screenshot]
[image: google search proof]

Comment: Do you mean "." vs "H2O.ai"?

Comment: yes how is that possible it still intrigues me, plz explain. @Josefz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those characters in ".", "H2O.ai" or "Ｈ２Ｏ.ａｉ" strings come from different [Unicode](https://home.unicode.org/basic-info/overview/) [subranges (blocks)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block), except the full stops.

You can check their [codepoints](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt) using the following *Python* code snippet; dots (full stops) are removed from sample test string:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import unicodedata
string = ' H2Oai Ｈ２Ｏａｉ'                 # ℍ Ⓗ②Ⓞⓐⓘ
print( "\n" + string + "\n")
for letter in string:
    print( letter,                                # character itself
           '{:02x}'.format(ord(letter)).rjust(5), # codepoint (in hex)
           unicodedata.name(letter,'???')         # name of the character 
           )
```

**Output**: `.\SO\63984352.py`

```
 H2Oai Ｈ２Ｏａｉ

 1d407 MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL H
 1d7d0 MATHEMATICAL BOLD DIGIT TWO
 1d40e MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL O
 1d41a MATHEMATICAL BOLD SMALL A
 1d422 MATHEMATICAL BOLD SMALL I
     20 SPACE
H    48 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER H
2    32 DIGIT TWO
O    4f LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
a    61 LATIN SMALL LETTER A
i    69 LATIN SMALL LETTER I
     20 SPACE
Ｈ  ff28 FULLWIDTH LATIN CAPITAL LETTER H
２  ff12 FULLWIDTH DIGIT TWO
Ｏ  ff2f FULLWIDTH LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
ａ  ff41 FULLWIDTH LATIN SMALL LETTER A
ｉ  ff49 FULLWIDTH LATIN SMALL LETTER I
```

You can use printed codepoints in HTML entities like `&#x48; &#x1d407; &#xff28;`. Those will render as H  Ｈ